# Is there a way to draw a route on a floor plan which is an image file?

Tags: android, google-maps, indoor-positioning-system

I figured out a way to locate the position of a person inside a building and I'm able to plot it on the floor plan which is a .png image. I also have geo-tagged locations on the image. Now I need to draw a route between the plotted location and the destination. Is there a simple way to do so?

Comment: Not inside of a floor plan from the best of my knowledge. There is no way for Android to distinguish what is what. You could write code that would handle it using something like regression scanning over the png, finding where walls are and where you are trying to go.Would take some logic.

Comment: Thanks for the input @zgc7009 Do you have any idea how Google Indoor Maps does it when you upload a floor plan?